# When I need to use "that" in Reported Speech

Tags: reported-speech

I have a question about Reported Speech: when do I need to use *that*?

For example, why do I need to use *that* here?

Original sentence:

> "We went out last night."

Sentence with reported speech:

> She said *that* they had gone out last night.

Why in this example don’t I need to use that?

Original sentence:

> "He works in a bank."

Sentence with reported speech:

> She said he worked in a bank

Comment: You should use it in both.  "She said that they had gone out last night."   "She said that he works in a bank."

Comment: There is no significant difference between the two sentences. BadZen is probably correct, but in informal speech we often leave "that" out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between your two examples.  One can include the word "that", or one can exclude it.  It is more likely to be included in writing than in speech.  The more formal the context, the more likely the "that" is to be included.

> She said that they had gone out last night.

> She said they had gone out last night.

Both are correct, the latter less formal.

> She said that he worked in a bank.

> She said he worked in a bank.

Both are correct, the latter less formal.

Here are some other examples where "that" is omitted informally:

- She said (that) she knew.
- You said (that) I could.
- They said (that) they didn't want to leave.
- We said (that) we would be there.
- He said (that) he didn't like it.
- You said (that) you'd seen it.

It can also be omitted in contexts unrelated to reported speech.

- I told him (that) I liked it.
- She knew (that) we were there.
- I thought (that) I knew you.
- I'm glad (that) I found you.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement @rjpond 's excellent answer, I will point out that journalism students, at least in the US, are explicitly taught to omit "that" in these constructions. Reuters, the British news agency, includes this remark in their **[General Style Guide:](https://www.trust.org/contentAsset/raw-data/652966ab-c90b-4252-b4a5-db8ed1d438ce/file)**

> Avoid the unnecessary use of *that* as in "He said that he was going to" etc. (page 420).

My point is that how we define *formality* when using this word depends on the context. Reuters is not known for generating tabloid-style articles.